# Appropriate cost for this custom magic item - Bracelets of Loyal Vermin?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, pricing

This item is templated off of the Amber Amulet of Vermin from MIC (pg 68).

> **Bracelets of Loyal Vermin**
>
> Body slot: Arm
>
> Effect 1: 1/day - Summon a Giant Wasp that appears and obeys your commands for 1 minute.  At the end of this duration, the creature vanishes.
>
> Effect 2: 1/day - Summon a Giant Stag Beetle, like above.

What would be an appropriate cost for this item if a player wanted to buy it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Combine two *amber amulets of vermin* and reskin

The ***bracelets of loyal vermin*** that the question describes can be made by combining into one magic item an ***amber amulet of vermin* (giant wasp)** (*Magic Item Compendium* 68) (800 gp; 0 lbs.) and an ***amber amulet of vermin* (giant stag beetle)** (*ibid.*) (1,200 gp; 0 lbs.). Such an *amulet* has a price of 2,400 gp. (This figure is reached by adding to the higher-priced item the price of the lower-priced item +50% as the *Compendium* details on Improving Magic Items (233).) Making this *amulet of vermin* (giant wasp and giant stag beetle) occupy the arms slot shouldn't change its price; it remains a slotted magic item.

Unless I'm missing something, these two items combined have exactly the effect described by the question's original magic item, the *bracelet of loyal vermin*.

### Exercise caution with the *amber amulets of vermin*

The *amber amulets of vermin* are, at low to middle levels among the game's most competitively priced magic items, easily obviating many encounters and staying relevant at least as a means of short-term flight sometimes to a campaign's early mid-levels.

This DM doesn't ban the *amulets*, but my campaigns' gentlemen's agreements see me wait to use them until the PCs do, and if the PCs never do then the I don't either, and if the players consider getting some *amulets*, I make it clear that I am comfortable with the campaign becoming a very, very bloody version of *Pokémon*. That's not to deter them or to threaten them but to explain my own need to maintain the campaign's verisimilitude: societies must be built around *amber amulets of vermin* because every level 2 commoner can afford to have 1/day for 1 min. a flawlessly loyal CR 3 Large or CR 7 Huge [monstrous scorpion](http://dndsrd.net/monstersVermin.html#monstrous-scorpion), and, y'know, that's kind of big deal. (As is, by the way, the difference between CR 3 and CR 7. So you know, that depends on if the DM views the errata issued for the *Compedium* (Mar. 2007) as impacting the reprinted *Compendium* (July 2013). *Sigh.* Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/56771/8610). This DM *really* hopes the reader doesn't have to care.)

Like boon traps (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37092/8610)) and *glyph seals* (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/119117/8610)), *amber amulets of vermin* are something a DM must plan his campaigns around if they are commonly available at the listed price. Culture changes if everyone who  is even slightly competent has a horrifyingly powerful siege engine dangling from his neck.

Comment: *Culture changes if everyone who is even slightly competent has a horrifyingly powerful siege engine dangling from his neck.* => As someone who cares very much about consistency and verisimilitude, I approve heartily. Like, remember the noble son who got mugged at the beginning of the campaign, when we were all level 1? Why didn't the fool summon a Huge Monstrous Scorpion from his amulet!!!